# Why is only some context data available in django template?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-queryset

I'm having trouble accessing some of the context data in a django template, probably due to a basic misunderstanding on my part. Please see abbreviated code below. My view is:

```py
class UserCourseListView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    
    model = CustomUser    
    template_name = 'account/course/list.html'
    context_object_name = 'puser_course_list'
    
    def get_queryset(self):        
        return CustomUser.objects.filter(username=self.request.user.username)
```

My model is:

```py
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, blank=False,)
    course = models.ManyToManyField(Course, related_name="course", blank=True)
    firstname = models.TextField(max_length=254, blank=True )
    surname = models.TextField(max_length=254, blank=True )
    nickname = models.TextField(max_length=254, blank=True )
   

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('patient_user_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

And template is:

```
{% for pcourse in puser_course_list %}    
          
    <dt>{{ pcourse.courses_joined.all }}</dt> # displayed in browser
    <dt>{{ pcourse.id }}</dt> # displayed in browser
    <dt>{{ pcourse.username }}</dt> # displayed in browser
    <dt>{{ pcourse.email }}</dt> # displayed in browser
    <dt>{{ pcourse.firstname }}</dt> # not displayed in browser
    <dt>{{ pcourse.surname }}</dt> # not displayed in browser

{% endfor %}
```

I am able to acces the user id, username, email and retrieve a queryset from a related model (using related name 'courses_joined'), but can't retrieve the firstname and surname? Any thoughts or help would be most appreciated. I'm assuming a context processor isn't required in this scenario as all of the data should be in the context_object?

Comment: The most likely issue is simply that those fields are empty (they have `blank=True`, so they can be empty), and thus there is nothing to display.

Comment: Thanks Solarissmoke. Sadly that's not the case. I've checked the fields are filled and tried with different users - still no luck.

Comment: Also, just to say I have re-run makemigrations and migrate - they are all up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We debugged this together in a session.

The issue was that `firstname` and `surname` were actually empty.
What wasn't empty was the `first_name` and `last_name` the model inherits from `AbstractUser`.

Removing `firstname` and `surname` from the model and using the other two attributes solved this issue.